# What is the difference between the sensitivity analysis and feature importance

Tags: importance, sensitivity-analysis

Pardon my question, but google does not find any resource on this topic.

My question is related to more if they are the same field, can they be used interchangeably or not.

As I understand in the sensitivity analysis, the variables are perturbed and their effect on the output is observed. In feature importance we want to find the same answer, but different methods are used more concerned with actual models used for predictions.

Answer (score 0):

With sensitivity analysis one variable is varied while the others are fixed. Permutation feature importance is an example of this.
Other forms of feature importance don't fix values but can use for example correlation of variables to the target or coefficients of models.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).